# How can I tell Mathematica to use ScientificForm also on the first column?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to calculate the value of a function for some particular values of the variable and put it in table. This is my code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
M = 511000;
z = 1;
\[Alpha] = 1/137;
b[T_?NumericQ] := Sqrt[(T (T + 2 M))/(T + M)^2];

i[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ 1/w ((2 M T +  T^2)/(M + T)^2 + (2 M (T - w) + (T - w)^2)/(M + T - w)^2 +   2 ((-M^2 + T (T - w))/  M^2)) (((4 + b[T] + b[T]^2) z^2 \[Alpha])/(12 (1 +  b[T]) \[Pi])), {w, 4.3, 100}];

Table[{T, i[T]}, {T, {10^6, 5*10^6, 10^7, 5*10^7, 10^8}}] // TableForm // ScientificForm
```

It works, but I get the `ScientificForm` only on the second column: how can I make Mathematica to use `ScientificForm` also on the first column?

Comment: why can't you just do `Table[{ScientificForm@T, 
   i[T]}, {T, {10^6, 5*10^6, 10^7, 5*10^7, 10^8}}];`? (btw, using `i` for function name is not very good choice)

Comment: @Nasser because it doesn't work. I use version 10.0 if it may be a problem.

Comment: I see. I do not have V 10. Will try on V 11.

Comment: ScientificForm applies only to non-arbitrary precision numbers. Try `Table[{N[T], i[T]}, ...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting N in front of the first column will do the trick:

```
 Table[{T, i[T]}, {T, N@{10^6, 5*10^6, 10^7, 5*10^7, 10^8}}] // 
      TableForm // ScientificForm
```

Comment: Tank you it works!